# Select directive similar to ui-select

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a select directive tat is similar to ui-select.(reinventing the wheel, for learning purpose).

I was trying to render a template inside the select directive and its not happening. [JSFIDDLE UPDATE 4](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/jsofs4gm/2/)

If i  render the template outside the parent directive its working working. fine.[JSFIDDLE UPDATE 3](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/jsofs4gm/3/)

```
<select-directive class="myInput" placeholder="type a name here">
<select-template ng-repeat="option in names">
  <span ng-bind-html="option.firstName"></span>
  <span ng-bind-html="option.lastName"></span>
  <span ng-bind-html="option.designation"></span> 
</select-template>
```

How can i render this template inside my directive and apply stylings to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add transclude do your directive. Transclude allows you to insert children of your directive into template.

```
myapp.directive('selectDirective', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'select',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
      scope.class = attribute.class;
      scope.placeholder = attribute.placeholder
      scope.options = attribute.options
    }
  }
});
```

And in template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="select">
  <input type="text" class="{{class}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
  <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</script>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/een9tvfn/

Comment: The text is merged up and down. can you update why is that?

Comment: Same problem is visible on your Fiddle version 3 https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/jsofs4gm/3/ , so I assumed that you wanted it that way for some reason. Anyway it is outside of this question scope, if you want answer for this problem, you can ask another one.